# HTML JQuery Image Selector

Tags: jquery, html, image

Whenever I select an image, the text "Window Image" shows instead.

This is the code where I need to be replaced by another image.

```
 <div class="product">
            <img id="model" src="images/casement.png" alt="Window Image" />

          </div>
```

These are the options where it should appear on product once selected:

```
<table>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="images/awning.png" id="Awning" class="wmodel wmodel-clickable"></img></td>
            <td><img src="images/sliding.png" id="Sliding" class="wmodel wmodel-clickable"></img></td>
            <td><img src="images/casement.png" id="Casement" class="wmodel wmodel-clickable"></img></td>     
          </tr>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.wmodel-clickable').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('id'));
});
$('.wmodel-clickable').tooltip();

$(".wmodel-clickable").click(function() {
  $("#model").attr('src', $(this).css('src'));
  $("#window-name").html($(this).attr("id"));

});
```

EDIT:
What should I add if I'm going to add the masked version of the selected image?
I made a masked version image so i can change color of it.

HTML for masked image:

```
<img id="mask" class="mask" src="images/casement-mask.png" alt="Mask Image" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
$("#model").attr('src', $(this).css('src'));
```

Namely `$(this).css('src')`.  There is no `src` CSS attribute.  It should be `$(this).attr('src')`.

Comment: It works! Thank you! what should I add if I'm going to add the masked version of the selected image?

Answer (score 1):

To show the masked version you could replace the image path:

```
$("#model").attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\.png$/, "-masked.png"));
```

That only works for PNGs and you would have to extend the replace regex everytime you add images with other extensions, or if the masked image doesn't end with "-masked".

So the better solution would be to add the filename of the masked image as data-attribute:

```
<td><img src="images/casement.png" data-path-masked="images/casement-masked.png" id="Casement" class="wmodel wmodel-clickable"></img></td>
```

Then you can show the masked image this way:

```
$("#model").attr('src', $(this).data('path-masked'));
```